# using sql join on three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have 3 tables which maintains stock entries for each products/items. These three tables like below :

```
Table : ItemStock (to maintain remaining stock of each item)

Id  ItemId  OpgQty  BranchID  CurrentStock
1     7       0       1            8
2     7       0       2            3
3     6       0       1            2
4     6       0       2            0

Table : ItemPurchase (StockIn)

    Id  ItemId   Qty  BranchID  
    1     7       5       1            
    2     7       4       2   
    3     7       6       1  
    4     7       2       2          
    5     6       4       1           
    6     6       2       2           
    7     6       2       1
```

Table : ItemSale (StockOut)

```
    Id  ItemId   Qty  BranchID  
    1     7       2       1            
    2     7       3       2   
    3     7       1       1  
    4     6       4       1           
    5     6       2       2
```

Desired Output (based on sql queries)
I want to have result like below : (part of report)

```
Id ItemId  OpgQty  BranchId StockIn  StockOut  CurrentStock
1    7       0        1        11       3           8
2    7       0        2        6        3           3
3    6       0        1        6        4           2
4    6       0        2        2        2           0
```

I was trying to get the desired result but was not able to do so. Please help!!!

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 1):

### try this;

```
select
m.Id,
m.ItemId,
m.OpgQty,
m.BranchID,
si.StockIn,
m.CurrentStock-si.StockIn StockOut,
m.CurrentStock
from
ItemStock m
inner join
(
select 
ItemId,BranchId,sum(Qty) as StockIn
from
ItemPurchase
group by ItemId,BranchId
) si on si.ItemId=m.ItemId and si.BranchId=m.BranchId
```

Comment: This answers your question! @Vivek

Comment: I said @vivek should try your answer because it gets the desired output.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar i don't see use of ItemSale table in your answer. Not sure , how would it work correctly without using ItemSale table records.

Comment: @vivek bacause sale=in - current

Answer (score 1):

A very simple query that gives the desired result is :

```
select *,
       (select sum(Qty) 
        from ItemPurchase 
        where ItemPurchase.ItemId = ItemStock.ItemId and 
              ItemPurchase.BranchId = ItemStock.BranchId) as StockIn,
       (select sum(Qty) 
        from ItemSale 
        where ItemSale.ItemId = ItemStock.ItemId and 
              ItemSale.BranchId = ItemStock.BranchId) as StockOut
from ItemStock
```

Answer (score 0):

Two subqueries with `group by` and aggregation will get what you want.

```
select 
    s.*, 
    coalesce([ip].StockIn, 0) as StockIn,  -- In case of no records in ItemPurchase or ItemSale, coalesce is neccessary.
    coalesce([is].StockOut, 0) as StockOut
from ItemStock s
left join (
    select sum(Qty) as StockIn, ItemId, BranchId
    from ItemPurchase
    group by ItemId, BranchId
) [ip] on s.ItemId = [ip].ItemId and s.BranchId = [ip].BranchId
left join (
    select sum(Qty) as StockOut, ItemId, BranchId
    from ItemSale 
    group by ItemId, BranchId
) [is] on s.ItemId = [is].ItemId and s.BranchId = [is].BranchId
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b70d6/3) in sqlfiddle.

Comment: not getting the desired result on actual entries. I am getting more than one record for the same item and branch.

Comment: @vivek We can not see what is your actual entries, so we also can not find out where is wrong, this sql get the result based on your sample data. Or you'd better post what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Please 
 [Try This](http://rextester.com/UXRH99164) ... I hope you consider this too.

Comment: not getting the desired result on actual entries. I am getting more than one record for the same item and branch. still looking what's the issue.

Comment: @vivek My script looks like I got your desired output.